# Исправление в блоке "Как задавать вопросы" на Мете

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, мета

На [странице задания вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) справа присутствует информационный блок:

> [image: блок]

Требуется заменить "пользователей" на "участников", поправить предлог, чтобы было "ознакомьтесь со справкой", а также исправить опечатку в слове "которые".

Указанные строки в transifex не обнаружены, к сожалению.

Comment: Вот интересно. Справка рекомендует всегда ссылаться на пользователей/участников, которых мы обсуждаем. А недавняя ситуация показала, что лучше бы вообще не обсуждать *участников*, а вместо этого обсуждать *действия (поведение)*.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если приписочка "когда это возможно", так что наверное некоторые ситуации можно отнести к невозможным :) С другой стороны, т.к. на SO почти всё прозрачно, даже не дав конкретную ссылку, можно вычислить о ком речь.

Comment: если->есть (время фикса истекло)